# Create global variable from program parameter in Python

Tags: python, global-variables, parameter-passing

I'd like to assign an "external" value for a global variable in a standalone Python program from a command line parameter and let my functions manipulate it (please disregard the fact that using global variables is discouraged in general). I have tried like the following:

```
def my_function():
    global global_var
    global_var+=1

def main(argv): 

    global_var = sys.argv[1]
    my_function()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

But it doesn't work because of the following reason:

```
NameError: global name 'global_var' is not defined
```

The problem occurs in the `global global_var` line in `my_function`, the function seemingly cannot recognize this as global despite the explicit qualification as like this.  I guess that this is because my `global_var` doesn't exist before `my_function()`'s definition. But I cannot define my `global_var` at the beginning of the code (before `my_function()`) either because `main()` should stand at the end and `main()` parses the program parameters. Right?

Comment: "because main() should stand at the end and main() parses the program parameters." No, Python is not C nor Java. `main` is an ordinary function that just happen to be called `main`.

Comment: OK, thank, didn't know that. I have changed the order of the two functions (`main()` first, `my_function()` second), but still the same error exists.